# While loop runs once?

Tags: java, file, loops, file-io, while-loop

The split function does not work. for the last print statement, it gives me an `arrayoutofbound` error. Any help?

```
 while (inFile.hasNext())
            {
               String clean = inFile.nextLine();
               String[] nm = clean.split(",");
               for (int i = 0; i < nm.length; i++)
                {
                    System.out.println("at index "+ i +" string is "+nm[i]);
                }
               System.out.print("at index"+2+"Strin"+nm[3]);
            }
```

text file :

```
input1,2,3,4,5
input2,2,3,4,5
input3,3,4,5,6
input4,3,4,5,6
input5,3,4,5,6
```

output:

```
at index 0 string is input1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at filereader.FileReader.main(FileReader.java:33)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: use `readLine()` of `BufferReader`

Comment: I don't get an exception when I run it.

Comment: Try adding `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nm))` to see what's in the array.  If that output doesn't make your problem clear, then edit your question and add the output.  Maybe that will give us an idea of what else to look for.

Comment: @ajb it just prints the first of each line.

i edited the code with the output

Comment: Have you recompiled your code?

Comment: Try adding code to print out `clean`.  I suspect that `clean` isn't what you think it is, which means that the input file may not really look like what you posted.

Comment: @ajb OP confirmed that his program has pointed to a wrong file location, so no fix is needed. (Look at Ravi's answer)

Comment: @PhamTrung I think he typed in that comment while I was typing in mine.  :)  Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

The code seems to be proper to me and it should not fail like this. Only reason i can see is if there is a blank line in your input file, in which case `System.out.print("at index"+2+"Strin"+nm[3]);` will return a ArrayOutOfBoundException at `nm[3]`

Alternatively you can write your code like this:

```
 while (inFile.hasNext())
        {
           String clean = inFile.nextLine();
           if(clean != null && clean != ""){
            String[] nm = clean.split(",");
            for (int i = 0; i < nm.length; i++)
             {
                System.out.println("at index "+ i +" string is "+nm[i]);
             }
            System.out.print("at index"+2+"Strin"+nm[3]);
           }
        }
```

Hope this works.

Comment: still does not work. i have no idea why.

Comment: wrong file location. thanks tho!

Answer (score 1):

This gives you error:

```
System.out.print("at index"+2+"Strin"+nm[3]);
```

And that is because you either have one blank line or a line where there are less than 4 comma separated items. Try this:

```
System.out.print("at index"+2+"Strin"+nm[nm.length-1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the array nm does not have 4 elements at line

```
System.out.print("at index"+2+"Strin"+nm[3]);
```

Check that the arrays contains at least 4 element before printing the 4th element.

```
    // create a new scanner with the specified String Object
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(s);
    while (inFile.hasNext())
    {
        String clean = inFile.nextLine();
        String[] nm = clean.split(",");
        for (int i = 0; i < nm.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("at index "+ i +" string is "+nm[i]);
        }
        if (nm.length > 3) {
            System.out.print("at index"+2+"Strin"+nm[3]);
        }
      }
```